# Windows Indexing Service Query Returns 0 Results

Tags: windows, indexing-service

On Windows Server 2003, I have an Ektron installation (asp.net CMS) that utilizes Windows Indexing service for its searches. Normally this works great, but for some reason the Windows Indexing Service is returning 0 results for a query where I KNOW there should be results for. I am doing the query through the Computer Management tool in the Indexing Service area.

Does anyone know what the first steps are for troubleshooting an issue like this? THere are plenty of files in this directory but it's not returning any results.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen lots of times when the index service is up and running, but not actually doing anything.  A restart of the indexing service usually gets it going again.

Comment: The indexing service has been restarted several times.. still not picking up any results.

Comment: Does computer management show that new files are getting cataloged?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this doesn't cover it, but I am just going from the information you have given.

Have you checked the properties of the indexing object you are searching on to make sure the folder with the content in it, is in the indexing objects database / scope?

Also - the stupid answer - is indexing service running?